# How to read acceleration values using TMotionSensor

Tags: delphi, accelerometer, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I'm trying to read acceleration values using `TMotionSensor` using code like this, following the [example code](http://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RadStudio_XE5_Update/MobileCodeSnippets/Delphi/Accelerometer/) provided by Embarcadero:

```
lbAngleAccelX.Text := 
           Format('Acceleration: %6.2f', [MotionSensor1.Sensor.AccelerationX]);
           //This code shows angle values instead of acceleration

lbAngleAccelX.Text := 
           Format('Angle X: %6.2f', [MotionSensor1.Sensor.AngleAccelX])" 
           //It shows nothing! it shows only zero as a value
```

Testing on an Asus TF300T Android tablet the `AccelerationX` value seems to return angle values instead of acceleration values.  The `AngleAccelX` property only returns zero as a result.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why that is not proper? Is it a code problem or a problem in your math equation? It is easier to help when we have a very specific example of your problem.

Comment: You need to edit the question to include your code and a detailed problem specification

Comment: here is the method I used with angles to show the acceleration value, although I am getting only Zero as an acceleration value whenever I run the application! " begin
        lbAccelerationZ.Visible := True;
        lbAccelerationZ.Text := Format('Acceleration Z: %6.2f', [MotionSensor1.Sensor.AccelerationZ]);
      end;
      TCustomMotionSensor.TProperty.AngleAccelX:"

Comment: seems like there is a glitch in the delphi code itself! that's why Im looking for better solutions if there are any? the code is quite long so its no possible to include it the whole! but here is the link to the delphi code im talking about http://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RadStudio_XE5_Update/MobileCodeSnippets/Delphi/Accelerometer/uMain.pas#l94

Comment: what I need basically is to find the acceleration value over a mobile device exactly as you said when an earthquake occurs! now, Im using "lbAngleAccelX.Text := Format('Acceleration: %6.2f', [MotionSensor1.Sensor.AccelerationX])" //This code shows angle values instead of acceleration

Comment: Moreover, when I use this code "lbAngleAccelX.Text := Format('Angle X: %6.2f', [MotionSensor1.Sensor.AngleAccelX])" //It shows nothing! it shows only zero as a value.

Comment: I'm using Delphi XE5, an Android tablet Asus tf300t Im running the application on, platforms we are using are androids, smartphones and iPhones iOS5 & iOS6 that we could run the application on, although we are getting the same result on all of the devices!

Comment: yes, I'm compiling the exact example code I have linked above and everything else you mentioned in your comment I have done in addition to that I have used the codes of finding the acceleration values when it gives only zero and when it gives only the angles values! Thank you for your cooperation:)

Comment: Have you used the debugger to make sure your device actually has the `TCustomMotionSensor.TProperty.AccelerationX/Y/Z` properties available? If they're not available on your device, the values you're reading are meaningless. Look at the demo app `TAccelerometerForm.Timer1Timer` event to see how to determine this (or just set a breakpoint in that event at the `case` statement and step through the code in the debugger).